# GET DIAGNOSTICS ROW_COUNT with concurrent statements

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, plpgsql, transaction-isolation

I would like to use `GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT` in plpgsql code to get the number of rows inserted into a table by a `INSERT INTO` statement.

If I run multiple `INSERT INTO` statements almost simultaneously can I be sure that `GET DIAGNOSTICS` returns the number of inserted rows correctly for each statement?

I can illustrate this with an example, if this happens in the following sequence:

1. User A runs a insert into statement that inserts 10 rows into a table.
2. user B runs a insert into statement that inserts 5 rows into a table.
3. User A calls `GET DIAGNOSTICS rowcount = ROW_COUNT;`
4. User B calls `GET DIAGNOSTICS rowcount = ROW_COUNT;`

Will user A get a `rowcount` of 10 and user B of 5? Or will both get 5?

Comment: Assuming both users run separate transactions ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL **PLpgSQL** statement `GET DIAGNOSTICS` shows info about last statement in transaction (inside transaction you are isolated from other users). So users A will see 10, and user B will see 5.

PostgreSQL is [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) database and users are strongly isolated (usually). In one session you cannot to see in big detail work of other users. Maximum what is possible to see a committed changes of data.